# saving data to binary file

Tags: c, types, binaryfiles, sizeof

How much space a character takes when saving it to file in binary mode [8 bits or 12 bits]?

```
fprintf(f,"%ld",ch);
```

also if I save a long [say 5]
then how much space it gonna take 3bits [101] or 8bits[00000101]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It copies the number of bytes required to store a `long` on your platform (`sizeof (long)`). If it copied just the bits required to represent the number, you'd have no way of interpreting the data when reading it.

In your code though, you're copying to a string. So the character (probably ASCII) representation would be stored, not the binary number.

Answer (score 4):

```
fprintf(f,"%ld",...)
```

will convert your number to a decimal number and will take log_10(ch) bytes to store. 
When you store it with [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) it will take as much bytes as you specify.

```
fwrite (buffer , 1 , sizeof(buffer) , f )
```

Also attention as you will never store single bits to a file as the read write acess is bytewise and therefore always a multiple of 8.

Comment: an example input file consisting of 45 bytes, the ASCII text string: the/rain/in/Spain/falls/mainly/on/the/plain. When we say that the LZW algorithm reads the character "a" from the input file, we mean it reads the value: 01100001 (97 expressed in 8 bits), where 97 is "a" in ASCII. When we say it writes the character "a" to the encoded file, we mean it writes: 000001100001 (97 expressed in 12 bits).

I read this at [link](http://www.dspguide.com/ch27/5.htm ) so how data is always stored in multiples of 8?
this is little confusing to me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good helping tool you need for this: [**sizeof** Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof)

Quote:

> In the programming languages C and C++, the unary operator sizeof is used to calculate the size of any datatype, measured in the number of bytes required to represent the type. A byte in this context is the same as an unsigned char, and may be larger than 8 bits, although that is uncommon. The result of sizeof is the size of the type of the expression or parenthesized type-specifier that it precedes, and has an unsigned integral type which is usually denoted by size_t. sizeof can be applied to any datatype, including primitive types such as integer and floating-point types, pointer types, or compound datatypes (unions, structs, or C++ classes).

So basically: if you want to know how many bytes something will use, just use the **sizeof**.

**Be careful** however: *pointers*, and other elements that are in fact pointers, but are used differently (like arrays) only show the size of the pointer in bytes... Not the structure the pointer points to! And storing a pointer is of very limited use - next time the object you want to use might be in a different location in the memory.

Comment: actually I was implementing LZ compression method and I was confused at the point where I need to replace strings[length>=2] with its index number.
so if I replaced "ls" [16 bits] with lets say 257[its index] then how much space this 256 will take after replacing "ls".[more or less? and how?]